# Fetch Facebook OG data via api

Tags: python, facebook, api

Is there a programmatic way to fetch/scrap og data as done here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

I have some pages that were updated and I want new OG data to be fetched by FB. It is cumbersome to do all this stuff manually one at a time. I thought about using some browser based automation tools but using an API to achieve this will be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a HTTP endpoint you can call to force a rescrape. It is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#selfhosted-update